# python inside a loop append from list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a loop I'm using to assign individual values but I need to add a letter to the end of the assigned value.  Is there a work around for something like this?

```
alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']  
place = 0  
print alpha [%d] %place  
place = place + 1
```

It works when using a real value, but how can I iterate through this list when it's being used as the output?  The code I'm using is for ArcGIS so I will paste what I have below for reference.

```
for row in rows1:  
    name = row.getValue("Name")  
    print name  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(mapLyr1, "NEW_SELECTION", '"FID" = %s' %searchrow)  
    searchrow = searchrow + 1  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(mapLyr2, "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN", mapLyr1, 0, "ADD_TO_SELECTION")  
    for row in rows2:  
        row.tile = name + A  
        rows2.updateRow(row)
```

So the first loop selects a large feature and it's used to select the smaller features within it.  Then the name of the large feature is assigned to the smaller features within it, but I need to add a letter to end in order to keep each smaller feature's name unique.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are getting errors, but in the second loop, change your row variable to row2. You are already using row in the first loop.

Comment: What are you expecting `print alpha [%d] %place` to do? That's not even remotely valid Python code.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Do you want to append a unique character to each element of a list?  Where do these letters come from?  Your line print `alpha [%d] %place` isn't valid python.  Thinking about it more, maybe that line should just be `print alpha[place]`.  Is that your intent?

Comment: I'm trying iterate through alpha to assign a value to the end of the copied value from a few lines above. Holy Cow, I had no idea you could actually specify the variable as the index location!  That is what I needed.

Comment: I tried changing the second row to row2 and the interpreter didn't like it.  I changed it back so they're all 'row' and it works fine.

Comment: The question is where is rows2 coming from at the first place ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this :

```
import string

for row in rows1:  
    name = row.getValue("Name")  
    print name  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(mapLyr1, "NEW_SELECTION", '"FID" = %s' %searchrow)  
    searchrow = searchrow + 1  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(mapLyr2, "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN", mapLyr1, 0, "ADD_TO_SELECTION")  
    for row,letter in zip(rows2,string.letters[:len(rows2)]):
        row.tile = name + letter
        rows2.updateRow(row)
```

But you have to fix this rows2 thing. It's not defined anywhere. And also as mentionned by @Mike, don't use the same name "row" twice, you're using it in the first for loop and the inner for loop. You should use for row1 in rows1 and for row2 in rows2 maybe, but you have to define rows2 first.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was directly inputting the variable into the list index locator.  I didn't know you could do that.  I added 'place' to the beginning of the script so it always starts as 0 and then I added an if statement so it will repeat itself with it gets to 16.  I have 16 small features inside each big feature, so this keeps it going without having an index out of range error.  Here is my final script.

```
import arcpy, os  

#set map doc and the layer to be used  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")  
mapLyr1 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "NEW_BiState_Grid400_IowaSP") [0]  
mapLyr2 = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "GridIndexFeatures20") [0]  

#alpha will be assigned a letter to rows2 update, there are 16  
place = 0  
alpha = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']  
name = str()  
searchrow = 0  
rows1 = arcpy.SearchCursor(mapLyr1, "", "", "Name")  
rows2 = arcpy.UpdateCursor(mapLyr2, "", "", "tile")  
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(mapLyr2)  
for row in rows1:  
    name = row.getValue("Name")  
    print name  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(mapLyr1, "NEW_SELECTION", '"FID" = %s' %searchrow)  
    searchrow = searchrow + 1  
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(mapLyr2, "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN", mapLyr1, 0, "ADD_TO_SELECTION")  
    for row in rows2:  
        row.tile = name + alpha[place]  
        rows2.updateRow(row)  
        place = place + 1  
        if place == 16:  
            place = 0  
del mxd, rows, rows1, rows2, searchrow
```

Thank you for your help!  I know it's probably pretty stupid, but I learned something new.  :-)  I really that I had to use a %d because that what I had to do in my SelectLayerByAttribute function.  Again, thank you everyone for your help!!